# How do I post to an api in reactjs website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api

I'm a very beginner both in react and apis, so I have a question about posting to an api. I want that I will have to post the texts of my textarea to an api and the api will send some scores based on my text.

the thing is that the textarea probably would send something like this which is just the text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
```

but the api only accepts data like, there is a prefix part {"data":"snippetDescription"} or else it just gives an 404 error without the prefix part

```
{"data":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"}
```

so as you can see, my textarea doesn't have the {"data":""} part but only the pure text part.

so i tried concatenating that in the post method but it gives an error.
this is how i tried to concatenate the first part to the textarea text.

```
scoreanalysis = (snippetDescription) => {

    return fetch("api/score/", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        snippetdesc: "{" + "data" + ":" + "snippetDescription" + "}" //this is the concatenation which doesn't work
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        textdata => {
          this.setState({
            scoredata: textdata.scores,            
          });
          console.log(scoredata); //how do I console log scoredata
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  };
```

the textarea code

```
            <textarea
              placeholder="Enter your text here"
              onChange={snippetDescription =>
                this.setState({
                  snippetDescription
                })
              }
            ></textarea>
```

the error

```
Unexpected string concatenation of literals   no-useless-concat
```

I hope someone can show me how to concatenate the prefix part too so that I can send the data as the api wants so that the api can send back the scores. thank you

update:

```
  scoreanalysis = (snippetDescription) => {
    return fetch("api/scores", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.parse('{"data":"snippetDescription"}')
    })
      .then(response => response.json)
      .then(
        textdata => {
          this.setState({
            scoredata: textdata.scores,
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  };
```

not getting any data from the api..
showing error in console as

Comment: Shouldn't be using string concatenation in the first place.... should just be `snippetdesc: {data:snippetDescription}`

Comment: what about the inverted commas? can i add them too here

Comment: What do you mean by *"inverted commas"*?

Comment: sorry, i mean the quotations symbols ```" "```

Comment: You don't . JSON.stringify converts objects to JSON string

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse('{data:"textarea content"}')` 
You need to use JSON format in order to send/receive data.

You are not calling the function `scoreanalysis`:

```
<textarea
    placeholder="Enter your text here"
    onChange={snippetDescription =>
        this.setState({
            snippetDescription
        })
    }
></textarea>
```

Cheers!

Comment: you mean to say ```body: JSON.parse("{data:"textarea content"})``` ??

Comment: Yes! You got it!

Comment: okay thanks, and how do I console log the scoredata? so that I know that I'm receiving the scores

Comment: You should use `console.log(textdata);`

Comment: yeah, i know that but in which section of the code should i conole.log it to show it?

Comment: Here: `.then(response => response.json()) .then( textdata => { this.setState({ scoredata: textdata.scores, }); console.log(textdata); // <-- here }, error => { console.log(error); }`

Comment: it's showing ```Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"``` in headers section now. what could be the reason? telling me to replace the ```:``` after headers with ```;```

Comment: Change this: `.then(response => response.json())` into this: `.then(response => response)` and test.

Comment: That is in order to check what is the answer you are getting.

Comment: Comment all this: `this.setState({ scoredata: textdata.scores, });` and test again.

Comment: just did. still the same

Comment: the headers line. showing an up arrow below the : symbol after headers

Comment: Change this: `headers: { "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" }` into this: `headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" }`

Comment: Remove that header.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(String)` doesn't make sense

Comment: I have updated the code as you can see and its running but not getting any data @RafaelMora

Comment: i removed the json.stringify in the updated code @charlietfl as you can see